# What Project template to use when developing a c# amqp microservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

How should I build a c# app that's based on amqp instead of rest. A .NET Core webapi expects requests via standard Http and not messages from amqp servers like rabbitmq. I'm trying to develop a microservice using c# but the way the rabbitmq client works does not seem to fit inside of a .NET Core rest api, so is there a package that can make this happen or is there a .NET project template specific for this use case.

Comment: There isn't really a great answer for this, at least not in the standard templates. One option is "Worker Service", which provides the basic generic host and DI. However, you may want to consider using a web API template even if you aren't going to implement an HTTP API as the primary interface; it makes it easier to add things like monitoring and health checks later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .NET Generic Host in ASP.NET Core - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for setup etc.

You can then use messaging frameworks like [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/tutorials/quickstart/?kme=nsb-getstarted-top), [MassTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/) or [EasyNetQ](https://easynetq.com/) to interact with the broker (RabbitMQ in your scenario). I've used MassTransit quite a bit and highly recommend - really makes interacting with the broker a lot easier. I've also heard good things about NServiceBus, but haven't used it personally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Worker services](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/what-are-dotnet-worker-services) I have used it for other message queue technologies. [Here is a link to the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Here are some articles I found, in particular to RabbitMQ

https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/rabbitmq-in-an-asp-net-core-3-1-microservice/

https://codeburst.io/get-started-with-rabbitmq-2-consume-messages-using-hosted-service-e7e6a20b15a6